# Delphi XE2 DataSnap Server - Log client connection user/properties

Tags: delphi, http, rest, delphi-xe2, datasnap

I'm building an XE2 DataSnap server which will serve connections from REST clients.  My DSServerClass LifeCycle property is set to 'Invocation'. What I want to do is to log the details of all client connections to the server, including the following details : username, IP address, protocol, application name.  I can currently get these details using the following events :

DSAuthenticationManager - UserAuthenticate() : username, protocol  (using the standard parameters passed in)

DSServer - Connect() : protocol, IP address, application name  (using DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo)

What I want to do is just log once for all details, but it seems I can't get all the details I need in one event.  I tried using a shared private variable in the class but as expected this gave inconsistent results - the wrong IP address against the wrong username.  Is there another way to achieve what I want?

Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TDSServer.OnConnect` event (which is called after `TDSAuthenticationManager.OnUserAuthenticate`). There you have access to `ChannelInfo.ClientInfo` as you've discovered and also `ConnectProperties` from which you can read property values like this:

```
  Scheme := ConnectProperties.Values[TDBXPropertyNames.DSAuthenticationScheme];
  UserName := ConnectProperties.Values[TDBXPropertyNames.DSAuthenticationUser];
  Password := ConnectProperties.Values[TDBXPropertyNames.DSAuthenticationPassword];
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the response.  Unfortunately just tried those property values and they return blank strings, am I missing something else?

Comment: In my test, `DSAuthenticationUser` and `DSAuthenticationPassword` returned the same values as those previously passed to the `OnUserAuthenticate` event.

Comment: Are you using 'Invocation' as the server LifeCycle?

Comment: Hmm not sure what could be different, unless version - I'm using XE2 Update 3.  I've found another way which I think is OK to use :-      Session := TDSSessionManager.GetThreadSession; User := Session.UserName;

Comment: I'm using XE2 Update 4 Hotfix 1. You shouldn't accept an answer unless it solves your problem, to avoid confusing others in the future. If you've found another solution which suits you, post it yourself as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I'm using XE2 Update 4, and the UserName and Password vars are blank in that context too.

Answer (score 3):

```
procedure TServerContainer1.DSServer1Connect(DSConnectEventObject: TDSConnectEventObject);
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Conn->UserName=%s, Password=%s', [
    DSConnectEventObject.ConnectProperties[TDBXPropertyNames.UserName],
    DSConnectEventObject.ConnectProperties[TDBXPropertyNames.Password]
    ]));
  // 取 Client 端的IP 和 Port
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('IP =' + DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo.IpAddress + ':'
    + DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo.ClientPort);
end;
```